# Using GetType/instanceof in C# vs. alternatives

Tags: c#, oop, object, reflection, instanceof

I've come across a problem in a game I am making in C#. It's a simple tile based matching game, and the problem has come up for a power up I am trying to make:

Say we have basic tile types, circles squares and diamonds, which are all subclasses of Tile. Instead of having circles only match to circles, I tried to extract the "matches" behavior to an abstract Tile method: canMatchWith(Tile t). 
The Tiles also have two methods to add/remove Tiles they can match with.

So say we have a Circle tile in the middle of our game, and we have a powerup that says "Circle tiles can match with square tiles this turn". I would go through all of the Circle tiles and say circleTile.addCanMatchWith(typeof(Square)). Internally, we have a List canMatchWith.

Then later, I want to say "Circles can no longer match with squares" and simply say circleTile.removeCanMatchWith(typeOf(Square)).

This is my current solution, and it works great with no performance drawbacks that I've noticed (It's a tile based matching game, so these types are only evaluated once per 'move', not frame by frame). However, the voice in my head is telling me that this is a bad way to accomplish this behavior. So I have some alternatives:

1. Enums... Each Tile could be composed with a Tiletype type variable. This would be initialized in the constructor and set to Type.SQUARE for squares, and so on. Then, each Tile would have a List canMatchWith, and the functionality is the same as my original implementation. Except in this case, it's a little trickier. Say I have some circle subclasses, oval and elipse. I want ovals to be able to match with ONLY squares, but elipses can match with all circles and not squares.

The problem here is redundancy, my enum would now have OVAL and ELIPSE as well, and the Elipse class would have (CIRCLE, OVAL, ELIPSE TileTypes) as types it can match with. This is completely redundant, I want to just say "Circle" which I could with the types. I suppose the Tiles could have TileType baseType and TileType actualType.

2. Some form of behavior composition. Forget Tile subclasses, just give Tiles methods and an instance variable for List. Then, at runtime we can just say someTile.addCanMatch(new CircleMatchBehavior()). This seems silly, as I would have a bunch of classes just saying you can match with a particular shape.

In summary, what I am trying to accomplish is having multiple object types be able to interact with any number of different types. The question is, what should I be using for the Type. Is it okay to use GetType here? Enums? Or is there a better strategy someone would recommend? I'm trying to be as general as possible, these tiles should not have any hardcoded dependencies on other tiles, and must be able to change who they can interact with on the fly. Say I make a new Tile subclass, pentagon... well, Pentagons can match with Squares, Circles, and Pentagons. Easy with my implementation, but something is telling me this is a dirty OOP practice.

I feel like I have to use Types/Enums because I am not trying to say thisTile.addCanMatch(Tile someOtherObject). That is too specific, I want thisTile to be able to match with all tiles who are instances of a particular class.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not a skilled enough designer to suggest a complete design for you, but if there aren't actual *functional* differences in the way Circles and Ovals operate, it might be better to have all instances be class `Tile` and then set some sort of `Behavior` attribute. All circles on the board might be able to share the same `Behavior` object, and then when the rules change for a turn, you can set changes on that one `Behavior` object. This might result in less code duplication, if I'm understanding the situation.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, this is sort of like my #2 Behavior Composition. My fear here is Behavior explosion. For example, MatchesWithCirclesAndSquaresBehavior. See what I am getting at? If there are 5 types of Tiles, then we have 5 choose 1 plus 5 choose 2 plus 5 choose 3 plus 5 choose 4 plus 5 choose 5 combinations of behaviors. This seems even worse than GetType. However, I might be misunderstanding something in your suggestion. The Tiles themselves do whatever they want, one might do an explosion animation, etc. This is only for if the tile can match with another.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting Behavior be an Enum or an unmodifiable class. You may subclass it in ways, but primarily I'd just expect it to have an internal collection representing the type that it is (Circle) and the type(s) that it can match with (Square). Then, you can change that in a somewhat data-oriented way. I definitely agree that anything that would result in massive if/else/switch blocks should be avoided in favor of good object setup, but we also want to avoid writing a new class to account for some not-so-new variation on behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all shapes of a similar type will always share a behavior, then it makes sense to not store that behavior on a 'per instance,' level. Instead, you can have a 'CanMatchManager,' that stores a dictionary of lists, indexed by shape type. Then, when a circle tries to compare a match, it requests the types it can match from the MatchManager. Alternatively, the MatchManager can take in the two shapes, and determine if those match. This is the [Mediator Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html)

Comment: Interesting, so something like: CanMatchManager::canMatch(Tile one, Tile two) { return dictionary[one].contains(two)} where dictionary maps Tile Type to a list of matchable types. Then, if I want to add an interaction, I could say tileManager.addInteraction(Tile one, Tile two) and it updates like { dict[one].add(two), dict[two].add(one) }. That seems more efficient than what I am doing, in terms of the memory required (Take it from the instances, give it to a manager). But it's still using GetType right?

Comment: My real question is "Is it okay to use GetType" for this kind of problem. Or would it make sense to restructure my program to be able to not use Class names (Types). Part of me is saying "If it works, and the code is not complicated, it's probably ok in this case" but also "Instanceof and it's ilk stink of bad design". To elaborate on the first comment, dictionary would be Dictionary<Type, List<Type> > map. How do we get the Types? someObject.GetType() and typeOf(SomeClass)

Comment: It is still using GetType but could easily work with a Dictionary. At least, because it's central, you can easily switch how it works to an Enum. My big problem with Enum types, is there isn't a nice way to have a class say what it's Enum is statically and, at some point, it feels like duplicating a system already in place. Also, with types, you can always use reflection to allow your manager to work using inheritance as well...

I edited my answer to  link to the pattern documentation.

Comment: I like your solution a lot - Since I am working at the Type (Class) level, and not an individual object, it would make sense to have a Matchmanager of Types deal with this. The Tiles shouldnt care about any of the other Tiles, it's only the Game that cares if they can match (Some tiles have special interactions, but that can be handled). Also, it takes the Type out of the objects, which sort of minimizes it's use. I feel like if i'm going to use Types, I should stick them in one manager class instead of throwing them around everywhere. I'll leave this open a little longer for more thoughts,

Comment: But I will likely accept this answer. I don't like Enums in this case either... I already have the class names, why do I need to duplicate them? Enums have other uses, but it doesn't seem right here. So it seems that in problems like this, it's okay to use class names (Types) as long as it makes sense to and it's clean (MatchManager is very clean, the caller of MatchManagers methods doesn't care how MatchManager decides if two tiles can match, it just wants to know if they can). No nasty if/else/switch or anything like that

Comment: @user2045279 enums are useful when performance is critical.  For example, the subclasses of System.Linq.Expressions.Expression use enums rather than type checking.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question has already been answered and accepted, but I've did something like this once and I thought I'd just post the code here.

```
    public class TypeMatchManager
    {
        private Dictionary<Type, List<Type>> savedMatches = new Dictionary<Type, List<Type>>();

        public TypeMatchManager() { }

        public void AddMatch(Type firstType, Type secondType)
        {
            this.addToList(firstType, secondType);
            this.addToList(secondType, firstType);
        }

        public void DeleteMatch(Type firstType, Type secondType)
        {
            this.deleteFromList(firstType, secondType);
            this.deleteFromList(secondType, firstType);
        }

        public bool CanMatch(Type firstType, Type secondType)
        {
            List<Type> firstTypeList = this.findListForType(firstType);
            List<Type> secondTypeList = this.findListForType(secondType);
            return (firstTypeList.Contains(secondType) || secondTypeList.Contains(firstType));
        }

        private void addToList(Type firstType, Type secondType)
        {
            var matchingTypes = this.findListForType(firstType);
            if (!matchingTypes.Contains(secondType))
            {
                matchingTypes.Add(secondType);
            }
        }

        private void deleteFromList(Type firstType, Type secondType)
        {
            var matchingTypes = this.findListForType(firstType);
            if (matchingTypes.Contains(secondType))
            {
                matchingTypes.Remove(secondType);
            }
        }

        private List<Type> findListForType(Type type)
        {
            foreach (var keyValuePair in savedMatches)
            {
                if (keyValuePair.Key == type)
                {
                    return keyValuePair.Value;
                }
            }
            savedMatches.Add(type, new List<Type>());
            return findListForType(type);
        }
    }
```

The class was designed so that it doesn't matter at which parameter you supply what type; it checks type1.list has type2 and type2.list has type.

A simple example:

```
        typeManager.AddMatch(a, b);
        Console.WriteLine(typeManager.CanMatch(a, b)); // True
        typeManager.DeleteMatch(b, a);
        Console.WriteLine(typeManager.CanMatch(a, b)); // False
        Console.WriteLine(typeManager.CanMatch(a, c)); // False
        typeManager.AddMatch(a, c);
        Console.WriteLine(typeManager.CanMatch(a, c)); // True
        Console.WriteLine(typeManager.CanMatch(a, d)); // False
        typeManager.AddMatch(b, d);
        Console.WriteLine(typeManager.CanMatch(a, d)); // False
        Console.WriteLine(typeManager.CanMatch(d, b)); // True
        typeManager.DeleteMatch(d, b);
        Console.WriteLine(typeManager.CanMatch(d, b)); // False
        Console.WriteLine(typeManager.CanMatch(b, d)); // False
```

Comment: That's basically exactly how I thought about making it. Very simple and elegant, and small as well. Thanks for your input!